# React Router Shows Blank Page When Using <Link> . Stuck on this problem since a while

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code of a component named topbar which refers to navbar of a page,
as soon as I save the page it appears to be blank.
Please help me to debug it as I am stuck for a while on it.
As soon as I comment  the Link part , the page starts working instantly.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./topbar.css";

export default function Topbar() {
  const user = true;
  return (
    <div className="top">
      <div className="topLeft">
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-instagram-square"></i>
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-pinterest-square"></i>
        <i className="topIcon fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
      </div>
      <div className="topCenter">
        <ul className="topList">
          <li className="topListItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/">
              HOME
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="topListItem">ABOUT</li>
          <li className="topListItem">CONTACT</li>
          <li className="topListItem">
            <Link className="link" to="/write">
              WRITE
            </Link>
          </li>
          {user && <li className="topListItem">LOGOUT</li>}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="topRight">
        {user ? (
          <Link className="link" to="/settings">
            <img
              className="topImg"
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1858175/pexels-photo-1858175.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500"
              alt=""
            />
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <ul className="topList">
            <li className="topListItem">
              <Link className="link" to="/login">
                LOGIN
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="topListItem">
              <Link className="link" to="/register">
                REGISTER
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        )}
        <i className="topSearchIcon fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this component to render it ?

Comment: `As soon as I comment the Link part , the page starts working instantly.` Which part? Can you please make it clear?

Comment: The <Link> part

Comment: I am using the component in App.js to render it

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Make sure you have react-router and react-router-dom installed. Do you have any <Route> components?